# Interpreting ROUGE scores

Tags: text-summarization, rouge

I recently read the paper on [Salesforce's advances in abstractive text summarisation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.04304.pdf). This states that the ROUGE-1 score achieved of 41.16 is significantly better than the previous state of the art.

I also read [this paper on (mainly extractive) text summarisation techniques](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10462-016-9475-9). This compares ROUGE-1 scores of various text summarisation methods and shows ROUGE-1 scores between 0.3788 to 0.5190.

I assume that the scores cited above are just using different scales, but even so I am finding it hard to get a clear understanding of how ROUGE works. [This SO question says that ROUGE measures recall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38045290/text-summarization-evaluation-bleu-vs-rouge), but that is [contradicted by this post that covers both precision and recall](http://text-analytics101.rxnlp.com/2017/01/how-rouge-works-for-evaluation-of.html).

I can understand that a higher score shows improvement over previous scores. I can also understand that abstractive text summarisation is harder than extractive text summarisation. Presumably, as a researcher you would always be trying to get a better score than the previous techniques. But as a user of these methods I need to gauge how far I can rely on the algorithms and how far I need to use humans to do some post-processing on the summarisations.

So my question has two sides to it:

1. What is the best way to really understand what a ROUGE score
   actually measures?
2. How "good" is a particular absolute ROUGE score? I'm defining "good" as "minimises the need for human post-processing".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> As a user of these methods I need to gauge how far I can rely on the algorithms and how far I need to use humans to do some post-processing on the summarisations.
>
> How "good" is a particular absolute ROUGE score? I'm defining "good" as "minimises the need for human post-processing".

There are two aspects that may impact the need for human post-processing:

- Does the summary sound fluent?
- Is summary adequate? I.e. is the length appropriate and does it cover the most important information of the text it summarizes?

ROUGE doesn't try to assess how fluent the summary is: ROUGE only tries to assess the adequacy, by simply counting how many n-grams in your generated summary match the n-grams in your reference summary (or summaries, as ROUGE supports multi-reference corpora).

From https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Automatic_summarization&oldid=808057887#Document_summarization:

> If there are multiple references, the ROUGE-1 scores are averaged. Because ROUGE is based only on content overlap, it can determine if the same general concepts are discussed between an automatic summary and a reference summary, but it cannot determine if the result is coherent or the sentences flow together in a sensible manner. *High-order n-gram ROUGE measures try to judge fluency to some degree.* Note that ROUGE is similar to the BLEU measure for machine translation, but BLEU is precision-based, because translation systems favor accuracy.

Note that BLEU has the same issue, as you can see on these correlation plots, taken from {1}:

[image]

> What is the best way to really understand what a ROUGE score actually measures?

In short and approximately:

- ROUGE-n recall=40% means that 40% of the n-grams in the *reference* summary are also present in the *generated* summary.
- ROUGE-n precision=40% means that 40% of the n-grams in the *generated* summary are also present in the *reference* summary.
- ROUGE-n F1-score=40% is  more difficult to interpret, like any F1-score.

ROUGE is more interpretable than BLEU (from {2}: "Other Known Deficiencies of Bleu: Scores hard to interpret"). I said approximately because the original ROUGE implementation from the paper that introduced ROUGE {3} may perform a few more things such as stemming.

---

References:

- {1} Callison-Burch, Chris, Miles Osborne, and Philipp Koehn. "Re-evaluation the Role of Bleu in Machine Translation Research." In EACL, vol. 6, pp. 249-256. 2006. https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=8900239586727494087&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5 ;
- {2} Slides of 1:
  https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/60f4/f98ff57be60a786803a88f5e7e970b35c79e.pdf  ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20171107013117/https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/60f4/f98ff57be60a786803a88f5e7e970b35c79e.pdf))
- {3} Lin, Chin-Yew. "Rouge: A package for automatic evaluation of summaries." In Text summarization branches out: Proceedings of the ACL-04 workshop, vol. 8. 2004. https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=2397172516759442154&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5 ; http://anthology.aclweb.org/W/W04/W04-1013.pdf

Comment: And when someone just says ROUGE-2  they mean ROUGE-2 recall?

Comment: @borgr I saw some code lines refer to fmeasure, check here https://github.com/yixinL7/SimCLS/blob/main/main.py

Answer (score 9):

You should read the [original ROUGE paper](http://anthology.aclweb.org/W/W04/W04-1013.pdf) by Chin-Yew Lin which goes in depth about the various definitions.

ROUGE is a score of overlapping words. ROUGE-N refers to overlapping n-grams. Specifically:

$$
\frac{\sum_{r}\sum_s\text{match}(\text{gram}_{s,c})}{\sum_{r}\sum_s\text{count}(\text{gram}_s)}
$$

I tried to simplify the notation when compared with the original paper. Let's assume we are calculating ROUGE-2, aka bigram matches. The numerator $\sum_s$ loops through all bigrams in a single reference summary and calculates the number of times a matching bigram is found in the candidate summary (proposed by the summarization algorithm). If there are more than one reference summary, $\sum_r$ ensures we repeat the process over all reference summaries.

The denominator simply counts the total number of bigrams in all reference summaries. This is the process for one document-summary pair. You repeat the process for all documents, and average all the scores and that gives you a ROUGE-N score. So a higher score would mean that on average there is a high overlap of n-grams between your summaries and the references.

Example:

- S1. *police killed the gunman*
- S2. police kill **the gunman**
- S3. **the gunman** kill police

S1 is the reference and S2 and S3 are candidates. Note S2 and S3 both have one overlapping bigram with the reference, so they have the same ROUGE-2 score, although S2 should be better. An additional ROUGE-L score deals with this, where L stands for Longest Common Subsequence. In S2, the first word and last two words match the reference, so it scores 3/4, whereas S3 only matches the bigram, so scores 2/4. See the paper for more details